# How to convert inputs values to JavaScript object?

Tags: jquery

I have the following input DOM nodes:

```
<input type="text", name="name", "value": "Erik">
<input type="text", name="age", "value": "25">
```

I need to make object from the DOM above like the following:

```
{
    name: "Erik",
    age: 25
}
```

How to do it with jQuery?

**EDIT:** I need something like the following:

```
var result = $('input[name]').map(function (i, input) {
   var result = {};
   result[input.name] = input.value;       

   return result;
});
```

But $.map method returns array instead object;

Comment: it should look like this in first place, remove the quotes from value `<input type="text", name="name", value: "Erik">`

Answer (score 2):

Well, if using JQuery you have to reference them somehow. Given that you have no specific class applied, you can try something like this, which gathers all input values from your page:

```
var myValue = {};

$('input').each(function(){
    myValue[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
}
```

If you only want to get the names of specific input elements on your page, then you must refine the $('input') selector to something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can capture your values in an object

```
var obj = {
  name: $("input[name='name']").val(),
  age: $("input[name='age']").val()
};
console.log(obj);
```